# Generics, Iterator -> cannot access the inner class function

Tags: java, eclipse, iterator

I am trying to learn Generics and Iterators in java and have created following code ->

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

public class Deque<Item> implements Iterable<Item> 
{
    private int           N;        // number of elements on list
    private Node<Item>  pre;        // sentinel before first item
    private Node<Item> post;        // sentinel after last item

    /* 
     * linked list node helper data type
     */
    private static class Node<Item> 
    {
        private      Item  item;
        private Node<Item> next;
        private Node<Item> prev;
    }//class Node<Item> ends

    /*
     *construct an empty deque
     */
       public Deque()                                                        
       {
           pre       = new Node<Item>();
           post      = new Node<Item>();
           pre.item  =             null;
           post.item =             null;
           pre.prev  =             null;
           post.next =             null;
           pre.next  =             post;
           post.prev =              pre;
           N         =                0;
       }//Deque ends

       /*
        * is the deque empty?
        */
       public boolean isEmpty()               
       {
           //if( ((pre.next == post)&&(post.prev == pre)) || ( N == 0 )  ) return  true;
           if( N == 0 ) return  true;
           else         return false;
       }//isEmpty ends

       /*
        * return the number of items on the deque
        */
       public int size()                      
       {
           return N;           
       }//size ends

       /*
        * insert the item at the front
        * This is extension of Queue, so First is the location near Post Node
        * pre-> <-post, pre->1<-post, pre->1,2<-post, pre->1,2,3<-post ...
        *      ^             ^             ^ ^             ^ ^ ^
        *      |             |             | |             | | |
        * initial           these all are the effects of addFirst()  
        * condition                   
        */
       public void addFirst(Item item)        
       {
            //System.out.println("We are outside ListIterator - addFirst");
           if( isEmpty() )                                   //here pre.next == post.prev
           {
               //System.out.println("We are inside isEmpty");
               Node<Item> NewNode = new Node<Item>();
               NewNode.item       =             item;
               NewNode.next       =             post;
               post.prev          =          NewNode;
               NewNode.prev       =              pre;
               pre.next           =          NewNode;
                                                 N++;
               //System.out.println(NewNode.item);                                  
           }//if ends
           else                                             //here pre.next->1.prev & X.next->post
           {
               //System.out.println("We are inside !isEmpty");
               Node<Item> NewNode = new Node<Item>();
               Node<Item>    last =        post.prev;
               NewNode.item       =             item;
               NewNode.next       =             post;
               post.prev          =          NewNode;
               NewNode.prev       =             last;
               last.next          =          NewNode;
                                                 N++;
               //System.out.println(NewNode.item);
           }//else ends                
       }//addFirst ends

       /*
        *insert the item at the end
        * This is extension of Queue, so First is the location near Post Node
        * pre-> <-post, pre->1<-post, pre->2,1<-post, pre->3,2,1<-post ...
        *      ^             ^             ^ ^             ^ ^ ^
        *      |             |             | |             | | |
        * initial           these all are the effects of addLast()  
        * condition                   
        */
       public void addLast(Item item)         
       {
            //System.out.println("We are outside ListIterator - addLast");
           if( isEmpty() )                                   //here pre.next == post.prev
           {
               //System.out.println("We are inside isEmpty");
               Node<Item> NewNode = new Node<Item>();
               NewNode.item       =             item;
               NewNode.next       =             post;
               post.prev          =          NewNode;
               NewNode.prev       =              pre;
               pre.next           =          NewNode;
                                                 N++;
               System.out.println(NewNode.item);                                  
           }//if ends
           else                                             //here pre.next->1.prev & X.next->post
           {
               //System.out.println("We are inside !isEmpty");
               Node<Item> NewNode = new Node<Item>();
               Node<Item>    last =         pre.next;
               NewNode.item       =             item;
               NewNode.next       =             last;
               pre.next           =          NewNode;
               NewNode.prev       =              pre;
               last.prev          =          NewNode;
                                                 N++;
               System.out.println(NewNode.item);
           }//else ends                
       }//addLast ends   

       /*
        * delete and return the item at the front
        * This is extension of Queue, so Last is the location near Pre Node
        * pre->1,2,3<-post, pre->1,2<-post, pre->1<-post, pre-> <-post... 
        *      ^ ^ ^             ^ ^             ^             ^ 
        *      | | |             | |             |             | 
        *     initial           these all are the effects of removeFirst()  
        *    condition                   
        */
       public Item removeFirst()              
       {
           if( isEmpty() ) throw new NoSuchElementException("Queue underflow EXIT" );
           else
           {
               Item item = post.prev.item;
               post.prev = post.prev.prev;
                                     N--;
               if( isEmpty() )
               {
                   post.prev =  pre;
                   pre.next  = post;
                   N         =    0;
               }//if ends                                  
               return item;
           }//else ends
       }//removeFirst ends

       /*
        * delete and return the item at the end
        * This is extension of Queue, so Last is the location near Pre Node
        * pre->1,2,3<-post, pre->2,3<-post, pre->3<-post, pre-> <-post... 
        *      ^ ^ ^             ^ ^             ^              ^ 
        *      | | |             | |             |              | 
        *     initial           these all are the effects of removeLast()  
        *    condition                   
        */
       public Item removeLast()               
       {
           if( isEmpty() ) throw new NoSuchElementException("Queue underflow EXIT" );
           else
           {
               Item item = pre.next.item;
               pre.next  = pre.next.next;
                                     N--;
               if( isEmpty() )
               {
                   pre.next  = post;
                   post.prev =  pre;
                   N         =    0;
               }//if ends                                  
               return item;
           }//else ends        
       }//removeLast ends

       /*
        * return an iterator over items in order from front to end
        * Returns an iterator that iterates over the items in this queue in FIFO order.
        */
       public Iterator<Item> iterator()       
       {
           return new ClassIterator<Item>(pre);
       }//Iterator<Item> iterator() ends    

        // an iterator, doesn't implement remove() since it's optional
        private static class ClassIterator<Item> implements Iterator<Item> 
        {
            private Node<Item> current;
            private int index  =     0;

            public ClassIterator(Node<Item> pre)
            {
                current = pre.next; 
                index   =        1;
                //System.out.println(current.item);
            }

            public boolean hasNext()  
            { 
                //System.out.println(current.item);
                return    current.next != null;  
            }

            public void remove()      { throw new UnsupportedOperationException();  }

            public Item next()
            {
                if ( !hasNext() )
                {
                    System.out.println("Queue is empty!!!");
                    throw new NoSuchElementException();
                }

                Item item = current.item;
                current   = current.next; 
                index++;
                return item;
            }   

            public void DisplayIndex( int indexVal )
            {
                if( index == indexVal ) System.out.println(current.item);
                else {}             
            }//DisplayIndex ends

        }//class ListIterator<Item> ends


       public String toString() 
       {
            StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
            for (Item item : this) s.append(item + " ");
            return s.toString();
        }

       /*
        * Display at random based on the indices supplied from the main
        */


       /*
        * main function for unit testing
        */
       public static void main(String[] args) 
       {
           int N  = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
           int K  = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
           Deque<String> list = new Deque<String>();

           System.out.println("Adding to the list by - addFirst");
           for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) list.addFirst( StdIn.readString() );
           StdOut.println(list);
           StdOut.println();

           Iterator<String> iter = list.iterator();
           // print random index value
           StdOut.println("Index Value = 1");

           boolean a = iter.hasnext();
           iter.DisplayIndex( 1 );

       }//main ends
}
```

The problem is that i am not able to access `hasnext()` and `DisplayIndex` functions with `ClassIterator` even though i have created an object of `Iterator`. Any help ?

Comment: I am seeing problem in iter.hasnext() and iter.DisplayIndex(1) function calls. Please forgive me if i am making some naive error, i am new to java...

Comment: `Iterator<E>` doesn't have a `hasnext()` method; it has a `hasNext()` method. Case matters in Java.

Comment: I am created an linked-list and i am trying to access its members via iterator...

Comment: Neither it has a `DisplayIndex()` method. It's in `ClassIterator`. You need to have reference of that type to invoke it.

Comment: Thanks alot Jon for your quick response. The one that you pointed out did help but still i am not able to access DisplayIndex(). I checked my case there but it seems fine. Any suggestion ?

Comment: @user3043882 `Iterator`s doesn't give you indexed access. That's the whole point. Why would you want to do that? And even if you want, you should have that method in the `Deque` class itself. Oh, and yes, please don't use the already existing class names.

Comment: Thanks Rohit for your quick response. But i couldn't understand, when i try to use ClassIterator<String> iter = list.iterator(); eclipse tells me -> Type Mismatch: Cannot convert Iterator<String> to Deque.ClassIterator<String>. So i am kinda stuck...

Comment: Hello Everyone could you give an example as to how can i access DisplayIndex() ? within class...

Comment: @user3043882 Because return type of `iterator()` method is `Iterator<T>`. You can't directly assign it to type `ClassIterator<T>`. I would suggest you to move the `DisplayIndex()` method out of the `ClassIterator`, and have it directly in `Deque` class.

Comment: Got it, Thank you RoHIT... I really appreciate this prompt help from your side...

Comment: So if i want to have indexed access can i use ListIterator ? and if so are there any pitfalls that i need to be aware of ? the reason why i am doing this is that i need to access linkedlist via iterator not directly.

Comment: @user3043882 Did you take a look at the `ListIterator` documentation? Does it have any method to give you indexed access?

Comment: Let me look at that, i think now i have enough idea, that i can finish it off... thanks once again...

Answer (score 0):

```
Check out my implemenation .... it works

import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

public class Deque<Item> implements Iterable<Item> {

private Node Head;
private Node Tail;
private int N;

private class Node{             // nested class to define nodes
    Item item;
    Node next;
    Node previous;
}


public Deque() {                          // construct an empty deque
   Head = null;
   Tail = null;
}
public boolean isEmpty() {                // is the deque empty?
   return (Head == null && Tail == null);
}

public int size() {                       // return the number of items on the deque
   return N;
}

public void addFirst(Item item) {         // insert the item at the front

   if(item == null)
       throw new  NullPointerException();

   Node newNode = new Node();
   newNode.item = item;
   newNode.next = null;
   newNode.previous = null;

   if(Head == null && Tail == null) {
       Head = newNode;
       Tail = newNode;
   }
   else {
       Node temp = Head;
       Head = newNode;
       newNode.next = temp;
       temp.previous = newNode;
   }
   N++;
}

public void addLast(Item item) {          // insert the item at the end

   if(item == null)
       throw new  NullPointerException();

   Node newNode = new Node();
   newNode.item = item;
   newNode.next = null;
   newNode.previous = null;

   if(Head == null && Tail == null) {
       Head = newNode;
       Tail = newNode;
   }
   else {
       Tail.next = newNode;
       newNode.previous = Tail;
       Tail = newNode;
   }
   N++;
}

public Item removeFirst() {               // delete and return the item at the front
   if(isEmpty())
       throw new NoSuchElementException();

   Node temp = Head;
   Head = Head.next;
   Head.previous = null;
   temp.next = null;                   // not required though its better to break the link
   N--;
   return temp.item;
}

public Item removeLast() {                // delete and return the item at the end
   if(isEmpty())
       throw new NoSuchElementException();

   Node temp = Tail;
   Tail = Tail.previous;
   Tail.next = null;
   temp.previous = null;
   N--;
   return temp.item;
}

public Iterator<Item> iterator() {        // return an iterator over items in order from front to end
   return new dequeIterator<Item>();
}

@SuppressWarnings("hiding")
private class dequeIterator<Item> implements Iterator<Item> {

    private Node current;
    public dequeIterator() {
        this.current = Head;
    }
    public boolean hasNext() {
        //return ((current.next!=null)?true:false);
        return current != null ;//&& current.next != null;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public Item next() {
        if(!hasNext())
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        Item temp = (Item) current.item;
        current = current.next;
        return temp;
    }

    public void remove() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }


}

public void dispForward(){
    Node temp = Head;                   //here did not assign memory as only reference was required
    while(temp!=null) {
        System.out.print(temp.item+" ");
        temp = temp.next;
    }
}

public void dispBackward(){
    Node temp = Tail;                   //here did not assign memory as only reference was required
    while(temp!=null) {
        System.out.print(temp.item+ " ");
        temp = temp.previous;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {  // unit testing

   Deque<Integer> de = new Deque<Integer>();
   de.addFirst(10);
   de.addFirst(9);
   de.addFirst(8);
   de.addLast(7);
   de.addLast(6);
   de.dispForward();
   System.out.println();
   System.out.println(de.removeLast());
   System.out.println(de.removeFirst());
   de.dispBackward();
   System.out.println();
   System.out.println("usnig iterator");


   // using iterator

   Iterator<Integer> itr = de.iterator();
   while(itr.hasNext()) {
         Object element = itr.next();
         System.out.print(element + " ");
      }

   }
  }
```